# Can PostgreSQL be configured to log user creation, deletion and modification?

Tags: postgresql

Is it possible to make PostgreSQL log user creation, user deletion and change in user permissions?

Answer (score 4):

Yes, add in your postgresql.conf and restart (or just reload) db server:

```
log_statement = 'ddl'
```

That works with createuser, dropuser wrappers, CREATE/DROP ROLE/USER and ALTER ROLE/USER statements as I checked:

```
2011-05-23 14:40:45 CEST STATEMENT:  DROP ROLE thomas;
2011-05-23 14:40:52 CEST LOG:  statement: CREATE ROLE greg LOGIN CREATEDB;
2011-05-23 14:42:36 CEST LOG:  statement: ALTER ROLE greg NOCREATEDB;
```

> log_statement (enum) - Controls which
>   SQL statements are logged. Valid
>   values are none (off), ddl, mod, and
>   all (all statements). ddl logs all
>   data definition statements, such as
>   CREATE, ALTER, and DROP statements.

http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/runtime-config-logging.html#GUC-LOG-STATEMENT

There is one drawback, that you have another DDL statements logged as well.